# Simple query is very slow which was working fine before

Tags: sql-server, performance

My SQL Server (using ASP.NET and C#, or even using SSMS) is very slow all of a sudden. It was working fine before.

For example, this simple query (in SSMS) is taking 14 seconds

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM AllAppointments
```

Table `AllAppointments` has a very simple structure with 7 columns, and only about 55'000 rows. This query was taking no time at all in SSMS and now it takes 14 seconds.

What can be the reason? How to find and how to fix?

Comment: The usual suspects are blocking or server resource utilization. Check server activity while the query is running for starters.

Comment: There are, normally, "better"™ ways to get the row count of a table anyway, using the the `sys` objects, such as shown here: [How to count the number of rows in a table in SQL Server](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/02/count-number-rows-table-sql-server/)

Comment: Check the **actual execution plan**, that'll tell you what's taking your time. Did you maybe add/remove a lot of rows recently?

Comment: Is `AllAppointments` a table or a view? Anyway if you get the actual execution plan in SSMS this contains the information to see where the 14 seconds is being spent (Plan compilation time? Wait time? Operator Execution time? etc)

Comment: @Larnu It was a sample query

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks for the tip. I executed the Profiler and came to know that another DB on server was attacked by spam bots. Once I fixed the other DB, everything was in control.

Comment: @marc_s Thank You! It is a table and reason was another db which was attacked by spam bots and 100s of records and queries were happening anytime.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thank You! It is a table and reason was another db which was attacked by spam bots and 100s of records and queries were happening anytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people coming to this link looking for same or similar issue.
It was a Spam Bot attack to one of the DB on my server which had slowed down the server. Once I fixed the issue everything got normal.

Comment: What IP address it was coming from?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Sorry, I didn't noticed else I would had shared